# What is vertical-align used for in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS and recently came across the property vertical-align. Having read a number of articles on what it is, I am still clueless on what it is for and when do you use it?

My understanding is that it is used for inline elements such as text, images, etc as well as text or other inline elements in a table. They cannot be used for block element such as div, h1, etc.

If my understanding is right, apart from aligning text vertically to say an image or using subscript or superscript, what other purpose does it serve?

Comment: I most often use it for centering text inside of cells of a table, by default the text is all top aligned in each cell and looks ugly.

Comment: I find `vertical-align` to be not at all useful, because block-level elements stupidly ignore the property.  It would be great if it could be used to vertically center the contents of a div, but sadly some ivory-tower person decided that that was not to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's always worth reading the specs if you want to learn about a specific property:
  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align
- A common use case is vertical centering (in combination with `display: table-cell`):

  http://jsfiddle.net/7eTb2/

  ```
  div {
      background: #ccc;
      width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      padding: 5px;

      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle
  }
  ```

  It's somewhat difficult to vertically center without using this technique.
- Another common use case is when it comes to elements that are `inline` or `inline-block`.
  See here for examples of what happens with different `vertical-align` values:
  http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html
- Another good link to read:  http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

However, it's *real use* is getting me upvotes, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a405015%20%22vertical-align%3a%20top%22

:)

Comment: Thanks for the example as well as the links. I had already read the link 'Hhat is vertical align' however was unsure if my understanding was correct. Inline-block is something I am just reading up on so am rather clueless when you would use them, what they are for, etc but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

It's used the vertical align inline elements indeed. Block level elements will ignore this property. So your understanding is right.

[This blog](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) gives some background information on vertical-align with some examples. It's mainly used to vertically position an image in a line of text. Or to replace the valign attribute on tablecells.

So it seems you are understanding it quite right. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) for the details on the vertical-align property.

Just to be clear; do not try to use vertical-align to position a blocklevel element like a div. It will not work, as you already mentioned, it's for inline elements like images in a line of text. Using `display: table-cell;` and vertical-align on an element is a hack, please use other CSS techniques to vertically align stuff in an div whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the link you posted prior to my question. So all vertical-align is used for is to vertically position an image to text or text to an image as well as to replace the valign attribute on tablecells? I also understand that the default property value is baseline. If so why use it in a reset CSS file. For example at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Different browsers have different defaults for different elements for `vertical-align`. Setting it to `baseline` for "all elements" can help to ensure consistency.

Comment: When using a reset.css file you want to be absolutely sure all browser are behaving the same. I guess there are some browser not using baseline as the default setting for all elements. So the reset.css will make this sure for you.

Comment: @thirtydot - It's all starting to fall into place now. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

Others have been mostly correct about vertical-align. The reality is that it works, just not how you think. It's for inline elements, not block elements.

In this case, a fiddle is worth a thousand words. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/JJfuj/

Answer (score 0):

vertical align, by the W3C and by how most(tm) interpret it, is only used/takes affect in elements that are table-cells (`<td>`), and on some browsers, elements with the `display: table-cell` declaration.

The rest of the time, it is largely disregarded by browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Vertical align is for just what it sounds like. It aligns the element vertically within the parent object; however, not all browsers interpret it the same.

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) a little more in-depth information on the parameter values available.

Comment: @B. Burke - I am sorry but can elaborate on your answer as I have already read the link you posted but it still makes no sense for me. What is an example of a parent object?

Comment: Absolutely I can elaborate:

The parent object would be the object that contains the element you are working with. An example of this would be a div with text inside. The div would be the parent object to the text element. If this div was the only container object on the page, the body tag would be the parent object to the div element. Make more sense?

Basically it appears you are trying to give more detail to a parameter that doesn't have it. :) It does just what it says: Aligns items vertically.

Comment: A parent object could be any block-level element, but imagine it as a simple square on a piece of paper. Draw a horizontal line through the middle of that square, and that's where `vertical-align` will place whatever you put inside the square.

Comment: B. Burke - Thanks. That makes so much more sense to me. I simply came across it looking at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css and had no idea what it was.

Comment: @Dolph - Thanks. Helped clarify the use of `vertical-align` for me.

Comment: Well, I noticed your question about that to one of the other answers. The thing is: They created a reset.css in order to reset the layout to what _they_ wanted it to look like (in this particular case, the developer wanted to "reset" the layout to use baseline as the vertical-align value). This is actually the default value, so that's why he's setting it (in case someone changed the layout to have a top alignment or bottom alignment, etc.).

Comment: @B. Burke: You should avoid linking to w3schools.com where possible. See: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @B. Burke @thirtydot- Thanks. This could be another question however is there a standard reset CSS I could use or should be using?

Comment: @thirtydot Wow. I didn't know that there was so much hostility. I just happened to link the first result for details for the css that came up in the search. Thanks for the piece of information.

@PeanutsMonkey No, there is not a standard reset. The only reason why this is even called "reset" is because the developer decided to call it that. Just remember to only worry about setting values that you require for your code. You're looking at an overly complex setup in that configuration and it's not necessary.

Comment: @B. Burke: No problem. If I'm Googling for a link to a property, I tend to use "property mdc" or "property sitepoint".

Comment: @thirtydot - I agree that W3Schools is a terrible resoource however having had a look at w3fools, maybe it would be worthwhile putting a resource together that everyone including newbies can find easily e.g. search, code examples where possible, etc. Be happy to help out in any way I can.

Comment: @B. Burke - Thanks. Not trying to overcomplicate the setup however am learning when to use it and when not to as well as the result of using it.