# How do I center text on top of an image in both dimensions?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering, rollover

Thank you all for your prompt feedback, it has been very helpful. One issue remains: Neither `line-height`, nor `padding` seem to be able to center **both** text that is long enough to wrap around *and* text that fits neatly on one line in the middle of the picture when applied in a table cell.

Oddly enough, the padding solution provided below by SwDevMan81 works flawlessly when applied to a div, but not a table cell...

I apologize in advance for my naivety; this is my first foray into HTML and CSS.

The code for the table is as follows:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class ="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    misaligned text
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    misaligned text
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class ="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
    .imgcontainer {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .imgcontainer img {
        float: left;
        background: #fff;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .imgcontainer a .desc {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1.0em;
    }

    .imgcontainer a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;
        box-align: center;
        background: #DDD;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);
        opacity: .75;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: `display: box;` is not a valid property, i think you mean `display:block;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not apologise for naivete. **Vertical Centering** is one of the most misunderstood parts of CSS.. and unfortunately, while there is an easy solution - to use the `table display properties` - they are not supported by IE7 and below..

So some form of hack is necessary for them, what is your support requirements?

The optimal IE solution I have involves a hack to both the HTML and CSS (and extra HTML element is helpful for them)

Here's the code that should work **without** IE6/7 support:

**HTML is as yours above**

**CSS:**

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 403px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.imgcontainer img {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}   

.imgcontainer a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}  

.imgcontainer a:hover img {
  margin-right: -200px;
}

.imgcontainer a .desc {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #cfc;
}

.imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
  background: #DDD;
  opacity: .75;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
}
```

### Working Example : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/ug7sv/)

---

and: **with optimal IE6/7Support**

add an `<i></i>` element between the `img` and `span` in the HTML like this:

```
<td class ="imgcontainer">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
            <i></i>
        <span class="desc">misaligned text</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Then conditional CSS : (add to a sheet that comes after the main stuff above)

```
<!--[if LTE IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.imgcontainer i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;  
  line-height: 200px;
  background: #DDD;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);    
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -200px;
}

.imgcontainer a .desc {
    display: none;
    width: 180px;
    height: auto; 
}

.imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;    
}

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

---

**OR** - without the extra HTML element or proper vertical centering

If you don't want to add the extra HTML `<i></i>` element for IE6/7 you could combine the first solution with a top padding solution, which won't perfectly vertically centre the text but should provide a graceful fall-back for IE6/7.

in which case the IE conditional CSS would look like this:

```
<!--[if LTE IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .imgcontainer a .desc {
        display: none;
        padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
        width: 180px;
        height: 150px; /* if adding to top padding, adjust height accordingly */
    }

    .imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
        display: inline-block;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);      
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

---

#### Update

as per comments, to make this work and retain border-spacing on the parent table you would remove the table CSS

```
table {
/*
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 403px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
*/
}
```

and then **ADD** `border-spacing: 0;` to the `a`

```
.imgcontainer a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

adding the above means the `span` which is set to `display: table-cell;` doesn't inherit the `border-spacing` on the parent table

#### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Cqsh3/) with border-spacing

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get this CSS to function properly with border spacing?

Comment: Yes.. remove all the `table {}` CSS or adjust your border-spacing to suit and **add** `border-spacing: 0;` to the `.imgcontainer a {}` CSS - IE works fine without any adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

here is a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/CKRZg/23/

Here is the new CSS:

.

```
imgcontainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.imgcontainer img {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.imgcontainer a .desc {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.imgcontainer a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;   
    width:500px; 
    line-height:500px;   
    background: #111;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: .75;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Due to your use of `line-height:500px`, this will only work for a single line of text. That might not matter, but it should be mentioned regardless.

Comment: If this is actually an answer, please include the markup and css in your answer, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: true, he can always play with margin-top and set a class to 2 lined images :)

Comment: Is there any easy way to deal with text-wrapping?

Comment: Read the comments above :). Set a Spanish around it, remove the line height and use padding to set the Spanish in the center. Or try to make it a table-cell with a vertical align applied to it :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried working with padding but it didn't seem to work in a table cell... See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with [padding](http://jsfiddle.net/AjQbp/5/).  This will handle wrapped text.

```
.imgcontainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.imgcontainer img {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.imgcontainer a .desc {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 50% 0;
}

.imgcontainer a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.imgcontainer a:hover .desc {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-align: center;             
    text-align: center;   
    background: #111;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: .75;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:block`, `display:box` is invalid. that will fix horizontal centering.

vertical centering is a bit more tricky since html is not meant to be concerned with the virtical layout of pages, only horizontal.

See: [What is vertical-align used for in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131922/what-is-vertical-align-used-for-in-css/6131967#6131967)

Comment: `display: box` is a CSS3 thing. Here's a random Google result: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

Comment: k, cool stuff. But still: not supported by IE, and experimental in moz/webkit. Not quite a deploy ready feature if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. Doesn't work in IE6 though.

**CSS:**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0 }
.desc { position:relative; display:inline-block }
.desc img { vertical-align:middle }
.desc span { position:absolute; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; line-height:100px; background:black; text-align:center; color:white; display:none }
.desc:hover span { display:inline-block }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="desc">
    <img src="http://www.uploadarchief.net/files/download/troll_face.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
    <span>Description</span>
</a>
```