# Center text on middle of a banner?

Tags: html, css

How do I create a banner and center text on the middle of it?

I have tried to use relative position on Wrapper and absolute on the image div but couldn't position.

```css
#banner {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
#banner_wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="banner_wrap">
    <img src="fe_bg_login_.png" />
    <div id="rockstar">
      <h1>I am a Rock Star Dude!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is the property you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center text on top of an image in both dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132000/how-do-i-center-text-on-top-of-an-image-in-both-dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align: center;` to do that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wm3j5w0/) to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;` property could let you do that.

```
#banner {
  position: relative;
   width: auto;
  background: #333; color: #fff;
  text-align :center;
}
```

The image in `absolute` position will not be centered if you use `text-align: center` in the banner, that's why I removed that absolute position and put it after the heading to get the same behavior.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvtb5uhc/2/)

**Source** : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align